# Calling an Integer into a Boolean

Tags: java, while-loop, integer, boolean

The section of my code that isn't working

[image]

```
}else if(bossOne == 3){
        int bossOneHP = 70 + bossStat.nextInt(10)-5;
        int bossOneOP = 27 + bossStat.nextInt(10)-5;
        int bossOneBP = 12 + bossStat.nextInt(10)-5;
        String bossName = "Spartan King";
        waits();
        System.out.println("Your first enemy is the Spartan King.");
        System.out.println("It has a very powerful attack, lets hope you have enough health.");
    }

    boolean keepPlaying = true;
    while (keepPlaying){
        Scanner choice = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 1 to attack.");
        System.out.println("Enter 2 to block.");
        System.out.println("Enter 3 to exit the game.");
        int selection = choice.nextInt();
        if (selection == 1){
            waits();
            System.out.println("You attack.");
            System.out.println(bossOneHP == bossOneHP - (OP - bossOneBP));
        }else if(selection == 2){
            waits();
            System.out.println("You block.");
            System.out.println(HP == HP - (bossOneOP - BP));
        }else if(selection == 3){
            break;
        }
        if (bossHP == (0 || >0){
            System.out.println("Congratulations you won!");
            break;
        }
        if (HP == (0 || >0)){
            System.out.println("Sorry you lost.");
            break;
        }
```

I need to have the integers be called to the section. This code is for the meat of the game I am creating for my programming class any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `if (boss >= 0) {` is what you need.

Comment: [Java Tutorial -- the conditional operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) for more on the comparison and equality operators.

Comment: What does it mean "integers to be _called_ to the section"?

Answer (score 0):

You want the 'greater than or equal to' operator: `>=`

```
if (bossHP >= 0){
    System.out.println("Congratulations you won!");
    break;
}
if (HP >= 0){
    System.out.println("Sorry you lost.");
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I'm not sure exactly what is supposed to do what but I will give it a try. It looks like you got a little confused.

For example:

```
    if (selection == 1){
        waits();
        System.out.println("You attack.");
        System.out.println(bossOneHP == bossOneHP - (OP - bossOneBP));
    }else if(selection == 2){
```

In this code you seem to be printing to console a comparison of the variable bossOneHP and bossOneHP - (OP - bossOneBP), which I think is not what you intended as the statement would print true only if (OP-bossOneBP) was zero  (basic algebra). What I suspected you intended:

```
    if (selection == 1){
        waits();
        System.out.println("You attack.");
        bossOneHP = bossOneHP - (OP - bossOneBP);
    }else if(selection == 2){
```

This sets the variable bossOneHP to itself minus (OP minus bossOneBP). Note you can also do it like this:

```
if (selection == 1){
        waits();
        System.out.println("You attack.");
        bossOneHP-= OP - bossOneBP;
    }else if(selection == 2){
```

Which is faster. -= sets a value to itself minus the following value as opposed to = which just sets it to the new value. Also == does a comparison returning true if they are equal while = sets a variable to a new value.

Second issue:

```
if (bossHP == (0 || >0){
```

I am assuming you want to activate the if statement if bossHP is less than or equal to zero. The || statement is a boolean operator (It compares the two boolean inputs on either side, whether that be a variable or a comparison or a function, and returns a single boolean value of true if either input was true), and does not function like the word or. To compare two numbers (in this case the variable bossHP and zero), you use one of several operators. They are as follows:

```
==  -returns true (which activates the if statement) if the numbers or objects (if they are the same instance, not if they contain equal values) on both sides are identical. 

<  -returns true if the left hand number is smaller than the right hand one (doesn't work on objects)

>  -returns true if the right hand number is smaller

<= -returns true if the left hand number is smaller or equal to the right hand number

>= -returns true if the right hand number is smaller or equal to the left hand number

!= -returns true if the numbers or objects do not equal each other (effective opposite of the == token)

!  -only takes one boolean on the right hand side and returns its opposite (this inverts the value essentially), if(!val) is equivalent and better to if(val == false)
```

The correct code would probably be something along the lines of:

```
    if (bossHP >= 0){
        System.out.println("Congratulations you won!");
        break;
    }
```

also instead of doing the while(keepPlaying) thing you could also do while(true) and run a break; command when 3 is inputed